# Reject my app in AppGallery because of this reason "Submit a formal version for release."

Tags: android, publish, appgallery

When I add an application (for the first time) to the Huawei developer account, I get a response with "Submit a formal version for release. "  What should I do?
I don't know what is the formal version..